# How can I have a latex type expression as a column name in R?

Tags: r, knitr

I am working on many kables using the kableExtra package. Say you have a dataframe,df, that is 5 rows and 5 columns.

in R you can do names(df)=c("A","B","C","D","E") for example.

Once you have the names of the dataframe set like that you can simply plug in the dataframe into kable to make a table.

My question is,
I want some of the names to include other symbols. For example I want one column name to be like

```
$\widehat{A}$
```

I.e an A with a widehat above it.

Is it possible to do this? if so, how?

Thanks

Comment: CTAN has no latex package called kableExtra , this appears to be more of an R question than tex? it might be better to ask in an R forum. (with no link to any latex package and no example document provided I couldn't even guess any answer, sorry)

Comment: Thank you, I will check out the R forums

Comment: @DavidCarlisle kableExtra is a R package that can produce LaTeX tables, and thus  imho this question is on-topic.

Comment: @Fran so I guessed but still it's only marginally on topic. If I was writing a C++ program that happened to be outputting latex and got stuck with the C++ syntax I'm not sure I should ask for C++ help here. Just because the R is generating latex doesn't mean that R help is on topic. Usually R users can post the generated tex and frame the question as a tex question to keep things clearly on topic. But anyway note I didn't say it was off topic (and didn't vote to close) I just asked if an R help site might be a better place to ask..

Comment: At least in Stack Exchange seems that  there are not a clear [place to ask about R specifically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65623/which-site-is-more-reasonable-for-questions-about-r-so-or-stats-stackexchange-c). There R tags in both  [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and   [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) but being this question related with LaTeX, seems  even more marginal  in these forums that in this site, that have also an  [r tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) with  now 474 questions.

Comment: @Fran I agree with you, and am happy to answer these kinds of questions on the site (you beat me to this one :)). But David wasn't also pushing to close anyway.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes. I have understood in this way, as well as his point of view.  Who focuses upon everything has, in fact, no focus. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but to pass to LaTeX `\widehat` you should write in R `\\widehat`. MWE in Rmarkdown:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r test, echo=FALSE}
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,4),B=c(6,2,4))
names(df) <- c("$\\widehat{A}$","$\\widehat{B}$")
knitr::kable(df)
```
````

[image: mwe]

Comment: Perfect. thanks!

Comment: @Quality For future questions it would be helpful to provide some minimal compilable code with your question as Fran did in their answer.

Comment: I will be sure to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up this a little while later. I've run the code in Fran's answer, and it works great. But I interestingly ran into a case in which nigh identical code

```
names(total_custom) <- c("Models Tested", "$df_{numerator}$", "$df_{denominator}$", "F value", "p value")

kable(total_custom)
```

produces the following result:

[image: Incorrect latex table]

In such cases, it is helpful to remember to also change the default `escape = TRUE` argument in `kable()`

```
names(total_custom) <- c("Models Tested", "$df_{numerator}$", "$df_{denominator}$", "F value", "p value")

kable(total_custom,
      escape = FALSE)
```

which, in turn, produces the following result:

[image: Corrected latex table]

As far as I am able to discern, this comes up when you're not immediately following your equation indicator `$` with a `\` indicator. Note that this problem persists when using other equation indicators, such as `\(` or `\begin{math}`.